# Conjecture: For any prime $n$, at least one of $2n^2-1$ , $2n^2+1$, or $\sqrt{2n^2-1}$ is prime.

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures

In my spare time, I came up with this conjecture:

> For any prime $n$, at least one of $2n^2-1$ , $2n^2+1$, or $\sqrt{2n^2-1}$ is prime.

Examples:

\begin{alignat}{2}
2 &\to\quad 2\cdot 2^2-1 &&\quad=7 \\
3 &\to\quad 2\cdot 3^2-1 &&\quad=17 \\
5 &\to\quad \sqrt{2\cdot 5^2-1} &&\quad=7 \\
7 &\to\quad 2\cdot 7^2-1 &&\quad=97 \\
11 &\to\quad 2\cdot 11^2-1 &&\quad=241 \\
13 &\to\quad 2\cdot 13^2-1 &&\quad=337 \\
17 &\to\quad 2\cdot 17^2-1 &&\quad=577
\end{alignat}

Can somebody prove this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The conjecture is unfortunately not true.

**Proof by counterexample.** Consider $n=19$.

We have:

- $2\times19^2-1=721=7\times103,$
- $2\times19^2+1=723=3\times241,$
- $\sqrt{2\times19^2-1}\approx 26.8887,$ which is not an integer hence not prime.

None of $2n^2+1, 2n^2-1, \sqrt{2n^2-1}$ for $n=19$ is prime, but $19$ itself is prime. Therefore the conjecture is not true.

Comment: Similarly 23, 31, 37, 47, 53, 61, 67, 71, ... . There more counterexamples than examples once you get past the first few primes.